# Словосочетание в роли приложения

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, словосочетания, приложение

Может ли в роли приложения выступать словосочетание?

Например: состояние — лицо кирпичом.
Или наоборот: исполнитель на фортепиано — мальчик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложения могут быть одиночными и распространёнными, т.е. словосочетаниями.

Примеры распространённых: *Это был очень важный документ —**свидетельство моей невиновности**. В глубине сада темнели развалины — **жалкие останки барского дома**.*

*Базаров, **уездный лекарь**, лечил крестьян.*

*Наши соседи, **люди воспитанные**, были удивлены. **Наследник большого состояния**, юноша был всё-таки очень скромным*

Ваши примеры некорректны, или нужно было дать полный контекст.

*Состояние - лицо кирпичом. Исполнитель на фортепиано - мальчик.* В данном виде это иллюстрация правила "тире между подлежащим и сказуемым".

Чтобы превратить в предложения с приложениями, нужно перестроить:

*Меня удивил его вид - "лицо кирпичом"*. *Там сидел исполнитель на фортепиано - мальчик.* (Приложение мальчик)  *Там сидел мальчик - исполнитель на фортепиано*. (Приложение исполнитель на фортепиано)*